# Select one column from database by two columns in the same table

Tags: php, sql

I have one variable in PHP, example `$to = "John Doe"`.

And I have this table:

```
ID     name     surname     username
1      John     Doe         jdoe
2      David    Smith       dsmith
```

I need to select `username` by `$to` variable with SQL.

How? I tried search something, but without success.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please include the code in the post, not a comment.

Comment: Not sure what your exact situation is here.. but this just feels like it's going to be full of inconsistencies. You really should be retrieving single records with a unique key (ID or username) unless you are performing a search.

Comment: I need SELECT username FROM users by string(John Doe), but I have one string with John Doe. I don't have two string(John) and (Doe).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any relevant information. It doesn't belong in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `concat()` the two fields together

```
$qry = "select username from users where concat(name,' ', surname) = '$to' " ;
```

Answer (score 0):

first explode your string from space

```
$explode=explode(' ',$to);
if(count($explode)==2){
    $qry="select username from users where name='$explode[0]' and surname='$explode[1]'";
}else{
    $qry="select username from users where name='$explode[0] $explode[1]' and surname ='$explode[2]'";
}
```

hope this will work

Comment: This works until Sara Jane of the Smith family comes along.

Comment: what result you want exactly

Comment: I need SELECT username FROM users by string(John Doe), but I have one string with John Doe. I don't have two string(John) and (Doe). This solution is bad, if I had John Paul Philip Doe (name= John Paul, surname= Philip Doe).